# Can't get response from Ecom Express API when using VerveLogic.HttpHandler

Tags: c#, postman

I have to integrate Ecom express shipping API in my code. This api is for pre generation of AWB Number at the time of order. Here is the document instruction to integrate shipping api :

Test Server URL:http://staging.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/

Test Server Credentials: Username: ecomexpress Password: Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$

Sample Request Body :

For PPD
username=ecomexpress&password=Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$&count=1&type=PPD
For COD
username=ecomexpress&password=Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$&count=1&type=COD

This API works fine with postman and generate AWB number also, But trying with C# code gives null object.

Check here the code I am using :

```
 var client = new HttpHandler.Client("http://staging.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/");
 var newUrl = "http://staging.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/?username=ecomexpress&password=Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$&count=1&type=PPD";
var data = client.PostData<dynamic>(newUrl, new { username= "ecomexpress", password= "Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$", count=1,type= "PPD" });
if (data!=null){ // do some stuff here }
```

I am using http handler nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/VerveLogic.HttpHandler/)

Please help or suggest a way in which I can get AWB Number using C# code.Also check the postman and document instruction here :

[image: API DOCUMENT INTEGRATION INSTRUCTION]

[image: POSTMAN WORKING SNAPSHOT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make this work using `HttpClient` and Newtonsoft.Json, so might be something with that particular library not sending the parameters as form-urlencoded.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "ecomexpress"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "Ke$3c@4oT5m6h#$"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("count", "1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "PPD"), 
        });

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://staging.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/fetch_awb/", content);

    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(body);
}
```

Where `ResponseObject` is:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    [JsonProperty("reference_id")]
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string SuccessText { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool Success => SuccessText.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    [JsonProperty("awb")]
    public int[] Awb { get; set; }
}
```